# POST запрос от клиента серверу Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, клиент-сервер

NodeJs Express App.

Необходимо передать массив от клиента серверу.

На клиенте формирую массив:

```
var path = [];
for(var i = 0; i < someObject.lenght; i++)
{
    path.push({ "path_x" : someObject[i].getAttribute("d")});
}
```

Отправляю на сервер:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getPaths',
    data: path,
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function (xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
});
```

На сервере пытаюсь получить ответ: /route/index.js:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/getPaths',function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

На сервере получаю ответ, что-то вроде этого:

```
{ 'undefined': '' }
```

Как правильно передать массив на сервер?

Comment: если используете `TypeScript` посмотрите сюда https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Синтаксис](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)

так как вы используете `JQuery` не гарантирую, но попробуйте
передать переменную `qwa` в объект `data`

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let obj = {
    data: arr
}
let qwa = JSON.stringify(obj)
// console.log(qwa)//{"data":[1,2,3]}
// console.log(typeof qwa)//string

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getPaths',
    data: qwa,
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function (xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
});
```

если не поможет, добавьте к вопросу метку `JQuery`, и да, высока вероятность что такой вопрос уже задавался